# Converting Number to Binary with 4 Bytes?

Tags: python, binary

I need to convert a Number into a `Binary Timestamp` object.
Here is the working function...

```
def parse_timestamp(binary_timestamp, timestamp_len):

      return binary_timestamp[3] * (2 ** 21) \
            + (binary_timestamp[2] & 0x7f) * (2 ** 14) \
            + (binary_timestamp[1] & 0x7f) * (2 ** 7) \
            + (binary_timestamp[0] & 0x7f)
```

My job is to basically do the exact opposite of this function (convert from number to binary timestamp), but I need some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I would say using struct.pack/struct.unpack will prove helpful to maintain endianness. I don't particularly understand what you mean by the left most bit is always 1, is that for all bytes or only the leftmost bit of your four byte binary timestamp.

Given the function, it might be quite possible for you to reverse the conversion by dividing the resulting number by each byte value?

```
Your number = a(2**21) + b(2**14) + c(2**7) + d
```

Which would then lead to a,b,c,d being your bytes apparently. 
To get a,

```
remain_1 = number % a #removes all multiples of 2**21
a = (number-remain_1)/(2**21) #this is the integer value of a
```

My confusion is where you need to pack with endianness and the issue of which bit is always one. You can extend the logic to the rest of the bytes and you should be able to get 4 bytes and then somehow combine them to the same format as binary_timestamp.

Packing like this maybe?

```
import struct
binary_timestamp[3] = struct.pack('>B',a) + 0x80 #add 0x80 to ensure the leftmost bit is 1.
```

So essentially, slice your number down based on the byte values. then pack and pad the bytes. Also I have no idea what your binary timestamp object is so this is just reversing the process of the function you added.

Comment: The leftmost bit in all of the bytes is 1.

Comment: Then the struct unpack method I have included in the original answer should be correct in restoring the value. Just extend the script to cover all 4 bytes and then use the pack. After that concatenating your bytes should be your binary timestamp. Bit-shifting would be good as well.